# HTML Folder Page Link

Tags: html, web, directory

So I'm in the process of designing my own professional portfolio website, and I haven't been able to find the right answer to my question (most likely cause I'm not asking the right question - cause I don't know how to phrase it). So right now, obviously I've created my index.html file, and my resume.html file, etc. And if you click on those links in my page it'll pull up the page: (mydomain.com)/resume.html. But if I go to another link on the page, let's say "Skills", wouldn't it just come up as (mydomain.com)/skills.html  ?? How do I get it, so that it applies after the resume.html, is it like a folder system? Basically I'd like to know how to format my files when I upload them/dev them, to showcase: "(mydomain.com)/resume/skills.html" That way it's clear to the viewer/audience that my skills are in my Resume section, cause it's resume/skills.html. Like I said, I can't find the right answer to my question, cause I don't know how to phrase it. I hope that made sense. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your set up should be index.html in your root directory, then make a resume folder, inside it create an index.html, this will be your resume, inside this folder also put the skills.html, this is how you will get yourdoamin.com/ resume and yourdomain.com/resume/skills.html

Comment: Ok great thank you. That makes sense. Like I said, dumb question but I couldn't find the answer. Haha thank you again!!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer.